Create Azure key vault accessPolicies with a loop
I created some virtual machine scaling set with bicep:
resource vmss 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets@2023-09-01' = [for vm in virtualMachines: {
  ...
}]

Now I struggle to create the access policies to a keyvault for these vmss.
I tried different things. e.g.:
var r = range(0, length(virtualMachines))
var accessPolicies  = map(r, index => {
  objectId: vmsss[index].identity.principalId
  tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  permissions: {
    secrets: [
      'get', 'list'
    ]
  }
})

This gets the error:

Error BCP247: Using lambda variables inside resource or module array access is not currently supported. Found the following lambda variable(s) being accessed: "index".*

or this:
var accessPolicies = [
  for (vm, index) in virtualMachines: {
    objectId: vmsss[index].identity.principalId
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    permissions: {
      secrets: [
        'get', 'list'
      ]
    }
  }
]

And gets the error
*Error BCP182: This expression is being used in the for-body of the variable "accessPolicies", which requires values that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. The property "identity" of vmsss cannot be calculated at the start. Properties of vmsss which can be calculated at the start include "apiVersion", "id", "name", "type".
*
How can I make a dynamic list of accessPolicies with bicep?

if you put your access policies in its own module, it will work with the loop

To keep the scene simple at my side, I directly used existing resources. I think it's also be suitable to your circumstances
main.bicep
param vmssNames array = [
  'wbvmss1'
  'vbvmss2'
]

param keyVaultName string = 'wbvmsskeyvault2'

resource vmss 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets@2023-09-01' existing = [for item in vmssNames: {
  name: item
}]

resource keyvaylt 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource keyvaultPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2023-07-01' = [for (item, i) in vmssNames: {
  name: 'add'
  parent: keyvaylt
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: subscription().tenantId
        objectId: vmss[i].identity.principalId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'Get'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}]

